# Automapper: mapping collection to single object via projection

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have a set of classes.

```
public class Student
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ScoreRecord> ScoreRecords { get; set; }
}

public class ScoreRecord
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

public class ScoreModel
{
    public int MinScore { get; set; }
    public int MaxScore { get; set; }
}

public class StudentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ScoreModel Score { get; set; }
}
```

I need to perform this mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Score, opts => opts.MapFrom(m => m.ScoreRecords));
Mapper.CreateMap<ICollection<ScoreRecord>, ScoreModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.MinScore, opts => opts.MapFrom(m => m.Min(s => s.Score)))
    .ForMember(d => d.MaxScore, opts => opts.MapFrom(m => m.Max(s => s.Score)));
```

The following code causes an exception:

```
var student = context.Students.ProjectTo<StudentViewModel>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
```

Exception info:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>        Additional information: Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[EFTest.Entities.ScoreRecord,
>   EFTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only
>   primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

If I do not use the projection, then the mapping works correctly. The following code is executed without errors.

```
var student = ctx.Students.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
var studentViewModel = Mapper.Map<StudentViewModel>(student);
```

Why mapping with projection is failing and how to fix it?

`Automapper version: 4.0.4`,` EntityFramework version: 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of a null check that happens when you have a map for a property. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

You can avoid it by setting AllowNullDestinationValues to false (globally or per profile). Or you can upgrade and set AllowNull per member.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is helped me. How can I set AllowNull per member?

Comment: First upgrade, then `ForMember(d => d.Score, opts => opts.AllowNull());`.

Comment: Now an error occurs if the collection ScoreRecords is null:  The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: Empty you mean, it's never null. Well, yes, it makes sense :) You'll have to make Min/MaxScore nullable.

Comment: I need StudentViewModel.Score to be null if ScoreRecords is empty. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, try it :)

Comment: It won't work because I set AllowNullDestinationValues to false :) And if I return this param to previous value, problem from my question will be raised.

Comment: You can always take over that ICollection mapping with ProjectUsing (ConvertUsing in 8.0) and you can do whatever you want.